# list size is 1 but front() and back() are unequal

Tags: c++, list, stl

The "error" causing code:

```
struct Edge
{
    int src, dest;
};

// Graph class represents a directed graph using adjacency list representation
class Graph
{
    int V;    // No. of vertices
    list<int> *adj;    // Pointer to an array containing adjacency lists
    void DFSUtil(int v, bool visited[], int &count);  // A function used by DFS
public:
    Graph(int V);   // Constructor
    void addEdge(int v, int w);   // function to add an edge to graph
    void rmEdge(int v, int w);
    int DFS(int v);    // DFS traversal of the vertices reachable from v
};

Graph::Graph(int V)
{
    this->V = V;
    adj = new list<int>[V];
}

void Graph::addEdge(int v, int w)
{
    adj[v].push_back(w); // Add w to v’s list.
}

void Graph::rmEdge(int v, int w)
{
    cout << "front == " << adj[v].front() << endl;
    cout << "back == " << adj[v].back() << endl;
    cout << v << " " << w << endl;
    cout << "My size is " << adj[v].size() << endl; 
    adj[v].remove(w);
}

int main()
{
    int n, m;
    cin >> n >> m;
    struct Edge* edges = new Edge[m];
    Graph g(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i)
    {
        int temp1, temp2;
        cin >> temp1 >> temp2;
        g.addEdge(temp1, temp2);
        edges[i].src = temp1;
        edges[i].dest = temp2;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i)
    {
        g.rmEdge(edges[i].src, edges[i].dest);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The input I am giving:

> 10 9
>   2 1
>   3 1
>   4 3
>   5 2
>   6 1
>   7 2
>   8 6
>   9 8
>   10 8

The output I am getting:

> front == 8
>   back == 1
>   2 1
>   My size is 1
>   Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Now if the size of the list is 1, then how can the front() and back() be different? And even if they are different, why is `remove()` giving segmentation fault when the value is present in the list (as the back() element)?

An observation:

[This code](http://ideone.com/21ciVk) gave `Segmentation fault` earlier than [this code](http://ideone.com/YBCG96).
Please pardon my horrible debugging approach, but this observation is implying that a `cout << endl;` is causing output to change in ways it is not supposed to. What is happening here, I am unable to make any sense out of it?

EDIT: I changed the `malloc` to `new` and still the same behaviour is persisting.

Comment: Looks like _undefined behavior_.

Comment: `list<int> *adj;` Why on earth are you using a raw pointer there?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - I actually copied the `Graph` class from [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/depth-first-traversal-for-a-graph/). Is that the cause of this error?

Comment: Run with the debugger to find out. Also you probably should use code copied from random places as long you don't completely understand it.

Comment: Any comments as to why this was downvoted? I'd like to address any issues.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - I do understand that code. It's just that this situation is unusual for me to debug.

Comment: Here you go: _"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example."_

Comment: Using `malloc()` for non POD types is almost certainly wrong. That also shows that you didn't understood what you're doing.

Comment: Well, wrt your previous comment: I am describing the erroneous behaviour, the problem/error and the code necessary to reproduce the error. The code may not be short, but it is definitely not redundant/superfluous.

Comment: And your observations when debugging that code are where?

Comment: You have a problem when you add edges, using those inputs, so what it does later is ... not really relevant. (It may interest you to know that c++ uses zero based indexing.) After you overwrite who knows what in the computer's memory, it's normal to find other variables with the wrong values, or class objects in an unstable state. (That's a long winded way of saying "undefined behavior", which was the first comment ... only you apparently didn't understand, so I gave the long version.)

Comment: @KennyOstrom - Would you tell me why the `remove` is not happening even though that element is present in the list. And BTW, even after changing to `struct Edge* edges = new Edge[m];`, the same thing is happening.

Comment: I already said the actual error is in add edges, way before that. Read the responses. See also https://stackoverflow.com/tags/undefined-behavior/info. Also, those telling you this is bad style (and very error-prone) are correct -- if you want an array of adjacency lists, use std containers for both.

Answer (score 1):

You're passing a "10" as a "v" to addEdge, trying to access the 11th element. The adj vector has 10 elements, hence you're writing somewhere in the memory where you should not. 
In any case, manual allocation and deallocation is recipe for trouble, consider using stl vectors.